# does not change font color in vs code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

i need a help with VS code. so when I start to compile code through live server to html and css I do not change the color of the font(html is connected to css), but when I compile through a bunch ctrl+f5 the color changes. Tried in different browsers firefox,chrome,edge.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Live Server extension. In my case, the problem was caused by an extension I installed on the Chrome browser (more specifically, that extension was Dark Reader). If you have some extensions turned on, turn them off and try again. I hope this post helps you.

Comment: I specially tried to download chrome I have a completely clean but still the color is not updated. When in the most html through the "style" change color everything works fine.Like html can’t see my file css